# How to prevent swallowing exceptions caused by unset expectations for a mocked object?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, exception, mstest

I am looking for a way to modify catch block depending on if it's executed during the unit test run or not. The purpose is basically to detect/setup mock expectations which are swallowed because catch doesn't rethrow.

I am using MSTest.

One obvious thing is using preprocessor but I don't think it works. Especially if to use DEBUG define. There should be an easy way to detect that, shouldn't it? I must have been looking for something wrong because I couldn't find much info on that.

```
try {...}
catch(Exception)
{
    Log(...);
#if DEBUG
        throw;
#endif

}
```

ANSWER: extract the body of the `try` into another method and test that instead. Provided by Jon and Ritch. See discussion under Jon's answer. Though thanks everyone for the contribution.

Comment: I may have understood the question wrong, but don't you think that testing code that's different from the code that will execute actually beats the purpose of unit testing? That said, you can create your own solution configurations with your own preprocessor variables, which might help…

Comment: @madd0: it maybe confusing. The catch above is quite correct. There are multiple cases, one of which is actually `catch(Exception)`. This prevents a unit test from reporting an expectation exception.

Comment: ...but you caught the exception, therefore its not expected? I think this is a misguided attempt to solve a problem that doesn't really exist. If you want to see how the code works in the presence of an exceptional state that is normally handled, pull that chunk of code into a separate method and test that method.

Comment: @Ritch: that's right. That's what I am going to do - extract code to a private method and test that instead.

Comment: FWIW, I couldn't tell if that was a straight answer or not.  I'm not talking about testing privates, but it seems to me that if you are trying to detect an exception being thrown by removing a catch clause, then you are violating SRP, and should look at refactoring in some way. Splitting the code into smaller functions is a best-guess first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How can you *test* the exception handling if you want to *change* the exception handling? Testing the altered behaviour doesn't test what would happen if you *didn't* alter the behaviour.

Hopefully your mocks have other ways of allowing you to validate expectations at the end of the test, so you can avoid the exception being ignored that way - and you should be testing that your Log and Fix really *does* happen when you want it to. (Testing logging is tedious and rarely worth it, but presumably Fix does something important.) You should also be testing that the exception *isn't* rethrown, if that's part of the design.

(As a side matter, catching `ArgumentException` is *usually* a bad sign to start with. But maybe in this case it's due to a poorly-designed library you have to use.)

EDIT: Just as a thought, if you're going to be able to test Log and Fix, that means you have to be able to check whether or not they were invoked. In cases where you *don't* expect an exception to be thrown, you should be able to verify that they *weren't* called. If they were, you've effectively proved that an exception was thrown.

Comment: @Schultz9999: That doesn't really change the gist of my answer. I understand the pain of having mocking expectation failures swallowed (I've been there too) - but look for a different way of checking them... see if the framework you're using allows you to validate at the end of the test that nothing was discovered to be wrong.

Comment: @Jon: off-topic, `ArgumentException` in my case is thrown deeper in the code when query parameter string is analyzed and some problems are detected.

Comment: @Jon: I am using Rhino. It throws as soon as something is violated.

Comment: @Schultz9999: My point is that ArgumentException usually indicates a *bug* rather than something untoward happening at execution time. That's why you shouldn't explicitly catch it - when it happens, you should work out why it's happened and change the code appropriately so that you don't call the relevant method with an invalid argument.

Comment: @Schultz9999: Yes, I'm not saying the exception shouldn't be thrown when something is violated. It's just that I'd *also* expect Rhino to remember that something *has* been violated and let you check that later. Does `MockRepository.VerifyAll` just pass if you've caught the exception? It may be worth pinging Ayende to ask if he has an idiomatic way of handling this.

Comment: @Schultz9999: I've just had another thought and edited my answer.

Comment: @Jon: I am using the suggested by library maker way - a couple `using` statements. http://www.ayende.com/wiki/GetFile.aspx?File=rhino_mocks.pdf. Dispose should supposedly call `VerifyAll`.

Comment: @Schultz9999: Okay, so maybe VerifyAll doesn't do it, but something else does. Unit testing code paths that swallow all exceptions is rare, but I would expect Ayende to have seen the issue before now. Perhaps there's an event you could subscribe to, for example. I'm trying to think of any way that *doesn't* involve you changing the production code.

Comment: @Jon: sent email to Ayende - maybe he'll help. As for the your paragraph in EDITED section, sure, you are right. Log and Fix are not actually tested but if they are mocked and cause unexpected invocation, it's fine because they are not in `try` any more.

Comment: @Schultz9999: If you're not testing the exception handling, consider separating the work that's done in the try block into a different method. Make most of your unit tests call that (it could be internal, for example) and then write a few tests which just verify that the *normal* entry point swallows exceptions and "fixes" them.

Comment: @Jon: that will definitely work. It's just somewhat awkward to create a method just for unit testing - the code in try is already just few lines of code. But still, that maybe the only good way. You should add this above into your answer so that I could mark the Q as answered and people wouldn't be confused why.

Answer (score 3):

I still stand by what I said in my comment and Jon seems to agree with me: changing your code on-the-fly just for testing kind of beats the purpose of testing.

If you need to "comment out" some exception handling for your tests to be viable, it might be a sign that you are catching exceptions too early in your code.

Maybe you should refactor your code so that it will not be modified for testing and then design further tests up the call stack to verify that exceptions are handled as you expect it.

Comment: no argument here. I am just trying to setup expectations for my mocks and exceptions  are swallowed.

Answer (score 0):

"#IF DEBUG" should be used with extreme caution. You are telling the tested code to act differently during test, thus rendering the test pretty close to useless. 
Catch specific exception types instead. No exceptions should just be caught silently - they must leave some kind of trail. So, either you throw an exception, or you do something that can be detected by outiders - including your test.

My advice would be to identify the different types of exceptions your code will encounter, and make a catch block for each. Remember that you can create your own exception types:

```
    private class MyException: Exception 
    {
    }
```

This can be used to organize your exeptions in groups that corresponds to the logic of your code.

If your program is not a windows- or a webservice, I would recommend that you do not catch the  basic "Exception" type. This is based on the philosophy that if the program meets unexpected behavior, it should be felt loud and clear. In this context, exceptions should NOT be considered unexpected (i.e. when using a database, one should expect occasional connection problems, timeouts, user issues etc.).